# How to make my small code of oneliner into multiliner in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, refactoring, python-3.7, one-liner

I mistakely onelinerized a piece of code, by using this [Onelineizer](https://github.com/csvoss/onelinerizer) and now am stuck trying to make it multiliner.

```py
(lambda __after: [__after() for self.argv.domain in [(parsed_url.netloc)]][0] if parsed_url.netloc and not self.argv.domain else __after())(lambda: None)
```

self.argv is  `parser.parse_url()` from argparse and parsed_url is `from urllib.parse import urlparse; parsed_url = urlparse(someurl)`. I think the code might been have written something like this:

```py
if parsed_url.netloc and not self.argv.domain:
  something
```

I cant deduce more, could someone help me make it readable again.
Also, `__after()` is not a function defined by me, its added by that tool.

Comment: Don't you have a copy of the original code that you fed into the tool?

Comment: Was the original code a multi-line function? (i.e., are you now looking for an equivalent multi-line function for this lambda?)

Comment: It wasnt a function, it was if condition iirc wait

Comment: Yes, the whole thing is equivalent to an `if-else` statement. That's for sure. I'm trying to work out the details of the `if` and the `else` parts, from what you've posted. Interesting...

Comment: @fountainhead see my updated post and give answer

Comment: Logical analysis of the one-liner code isn't getting me far, because the analysis is telling me that when the one-liner is executed, though the lambda will perform the assignment `self.argv.domain = parsed_url.netloc`, it will also result in **infinite** recursion of the lambda function. So, abandoning logical analysis, my instinct tells me that the entire one-liner can be replaced by an `if` statement (not an `if-else`), and the only thing inside the `if` block is the assignment `self.argv.domain = parsed_url.netloc`. Test it out, by making that correction and re-running the tool

Comment: When you re-run the tool with the one-liner replaced by the `if` statement, you should get back the exact same one-liner re-generated by the tool. That would clinch it

Comment: @fountainhead `__after()` is not a recursive call, since `__after` is just the `lambda: None` argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Onelinerizer uses a list comprehension to translate assignment statements:

```py
[__after() for self.arg.domain in [(parsed_url.netloc)]][0]
```

is equivalent to:

```py
self.arg.domain = parsed_url.netloc
__after()
```

so your entire line is equivalent to:

```py
if parsed_url.netloc and not self.argv.domain:
    self.arg.domain = parsed_url.netloc
```